# convert string in a foreign language to date

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, localization

I have these input:

> 27 februari 2014
>   14 maart 2013
>   7 november 2013

I would like to convert them all to date field as below:

> 27-02-2014
>   14-03-2013
>   17-11-2013

I have tried this method: `DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(s);` but it does not work, the error message was:

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown
>   word starting at index 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears as Dutch, you can parse it by passing `new CultureInfo("nl-NL")` to `DateTime.ParseExact` like:

```
string str = "27 februari 2014";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "d MMMM yyyy", 
                        new System.Globalization.CultureInfoCultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Use single `d` which would consider both single and double digit day part.

To get the formatted output use:

```
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfoCultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: do you know what is the reference of CultureInfo?

Comment: `System.Globalization`

Comment: i got this error:
Culture 'nl' is a neutral culture. It cannot be used in formatting and parsing and therefore cannot be set as the thread's current culture.

Comment: @Xarxas, how did you get this error ? are you trying to set the current culture to `nl`, just use it in `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: yes to NL, this is the code:
string str = "27 februari 2014";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("nl"));
        string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       Response.Write(formattedDate);

Comment: @Xarxas, not really sure, but try: `new CultureInfo("nl-NL")`, the current code in the answer works fine in VS on my machine.

Comment: @Xarxas, glad it helped, you may see [this](http://www.imiscommunity.com/error_culture_es_is_a_neutral_culture_it_cannot_be_used_in_formatting_and_parsing_and_therefore_cannot_be_set_as_the_thread) thread which deals with the similar problem

Comment: perfect! this is what i found : [link](http://socalmp.com/blog/template_permalink.asp?id=98) list

Answer (score 0):

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Parse3_Example) allows you to provide a CultureInfo, which may be enough for you. If not, and you only get one foreign language, you could simply replace the the words by the correct English ones.